# Cast from Response to unrelated type Dictionary always fails Alamofire 3.4

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, swift2, alamofire

I've just started learning IOS `Swift 2.2` development, I'm following an only tutorial whereby the teacher installs `Alamofire` (early version) into his Xcode project and then builds a http request.

The data that is returned from the call is of type `JSON`, the issue I have is I'm using the latest version of `Alamofire 3.4` and my `.GET` request is set up like so:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in

        print(response)

        if let result = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let weight = result["weight"] as? String {

                self._weight = weight

            }
        }

    })
```

Yet when I try to cast the response to a `Dictionary` I get the following error: 
Cast from Response to unrelated type Dictionary always fails

I've also tried using `response.result` within my `if` statement however the error still remains.

When I print the response I actually see all the attributes in a `JSON` object.

Comment: I've had this problem with Alamofire before too. Try casting it as an Array rather than a dictionary.

Comment: @rigdonmr still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by using: `response.result.value` within the `if` statement.